# How to get number of decimal places and plus one in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to implement plus function on last decimal place like

```
print(plusOne(0.0001)) -> 0.0002
print(plusOne(0.000001)) -> 0.000002
print(plusOne(22)) -> 23
```

Has anyone ever done about this?

Comment: Show your plusOne function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get your value ulp property and add it:

```
let decimal1 = Decimal(string: "0.0001")!
let next1 = decimal1 + decimal1.ulp  // 0.0002
let decimal2 = Decimal(string: "0.000001")!
let next2 = decimal2 + decimal2.ulp  // 0.000002
let decimal3 = Decimal(string: "22")!
let next3 = decimal3 + decimal3.ulp  // 23
```

or just simply get your nextUp or nextDown properties

```
decimal1.nextUp  // 0.0002
decimal2.nextUp  // 0.000002
decimal3.nextUp  // 23

decimal1.nextDown // 0
decimal2.nextDown // 0
decimal3.nextDown // 21
```

Comment: Can I ask something more ? Can I lock a number of places? for now if I use next up with 0.009, result will be 0.01. How about if I want result 0.010 ?

Comment: 0.01 and 0.010 are the same number. If you need 0.010 you need number formatter

Comment: If your intent is to keep adding 0..001 just store the ulp value to keep adding 0.001 indefinitely

Answer (score 1):

[truncatingRemainder(dividingBy:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2885641-truncatingremainder) Will help you to find the solution. Please refer to the below code snippet.

```
let x:Double = 1234.5678

let decimalPart:Double = x.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1)    //0.5678
let integerPart:Double = x.rounded(.towardZero)                   //1234
```