# Adding a double to all elements of a numeric array and return Array<Double>

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add NumPy like functionality to a Swift array where you can use the + or - operators to add/subtract a Double to every element of a numeric Array and return a new Array with the new elements as [Double]. Here is how I have implemented it in 2 extensions for Int and Floating point types:

```
extension Array where Element: BinaryInteger {
    static func + (array: Self, num: Double) -> [Double]
    {
        return array.map{Double($0) + num}
    }
    
    static func - (array: Self, num: Double) -> [Double]
    {
        return array.map{Double($0) - num}
    }
}

extension Array where Element: BinaryFloatingPoint {
    static func + (array: Self, num: Double) -> [Double]
    {
        return array.map{Double($0) + num}
    }
    
    static func - (array: Self, num: Double) -> [Double]
    {
        return array.map{Double($0) - num}
    }
}
```

As you can see there is a lot of duplicate code here. Is there a better way to implement this?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
extension Array where Element: Numeric {
    static func + (array: Self, num: Double) -> [Double]
    {
        return array.map{Double($0) + num}
    }
    
    static func - (array: Self, num: Double) -> [Double]
    {
        return array.map{Double($0) - num}
    }
}
```

The compiler complains at line `Double($0)` since Double doesn't have initializer for Numeric.

Answer (score 1):

Why use `Double` at all? You're just introducing potential precision issues for integer types that have perfect precision over integers

```swift
extension Array where Element: Numeric {
    static func + (array: Self, num: Element) -> [Element] {
        return array.map { $0 + num }
    }
    
    static func - (array: Self, num: Element) -> [Element] {
        return array.map { $0 - num }
    }
}

print([1, 2, 3] + 10) // => [11, 12, 13]
```

Comment: I need to add or subtract 0.0001 so I need the num to be of type Double. Also I need the result array to be of type Array<Double>. And you are right, there were some precision issues when I used it with Int array. My question is what is the right way of doing this in Swift?

Comment: @FaridRahmani Implicitly converting an array of any numeric type to Double, on the off-chance that Double was the final result you wanted, is not a good idea. If that's what you need, then you should explicitly make an array of doubles. E.g. `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0] + 0.1` or `existingArrayOfInts.map(Double.init) + 0.1`

Comment: @FaridRahmani Note that Double can not represent all fraction digits precisely. You better use Swift Decimal type. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67965026/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for the great suggestion. The precision issue was resolved by using Decimal instead of Double.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to check type of Element and force typecast instead:

```
extension Array where Element: Numeric {
    static func + (array: Self, num: Decimal) -> [Decimal]
    {
        if let first = array.first {
            switch first {
            case is Int:
                return array.map{Decimal($0 as! Int) + num}
            case is Double:
                return array.map{Decimal($0 as! Double) + num}
            case is Decimal:
                return array.map{$0 as! Decimal + num}
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        
        return []
        
    }
    
    static func - (array: Self, num: Decimal) -> [Decimal]
    {
        if let first = array.first {
            switch first {
            case is Int:
                return array.map{Decimal($0 as! Int) - num}
            case is Double:
                return array.map{Decimal($0 as! Double) - num}
            case is Decimal:
                return array.map{$0 as! Decimal - num}
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        
        return []
        
    }
    
    static func / (array: Self, num: Decimal) -> [Decimal]
    {
        if let first = array.first {
            switch first {
            case is Int:
                return array.map{Decimal($0 as! Int) / num}
            case is Double:
                return array.map{Decimal($0 as! Double) / num}
            case is Decimal:
                return array.map{$0 as! Decimal / num}
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        
        return []
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the code presented in the question is better than this, as there are lots of numeric types that this just won’t handle. `Int8`, `Float`, etc. And, IMHO, Alexander’s solution is best. With no offense, this is an unnecessarily brittle solution…

Comment: Ah jeeze man, don't do this, this makes no sense.